# Why the type of expression objectOfTypeT::class is KClass<out T>?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose we have generic function:

```
fun <T: Any> foo(o: T) {
    o::class
}
```

The `o::class`'s type is `KClass<out T>`. Why there is the out variance annotation, and why is it not `KClass<out Any>` (because `T`'s erasure is `Any`)

<sub>This out variance annotation screwed my nice reflection code</sub>

---

EDIT:
After digging a while, I found kotlin rely on `Object::getClass` to get a `Class` to create a `KClass`, the actual creation code has a signature like `fun <T: Any> create(jClass: Class<T>): KClass<T>`. However this leads to another problem. **The `o::class` should be of type `KClass<Any>`** because `jClass` parameter of that create method should be of type `Class<Object>`, since the erasure of static type `T` is just `Any` (or `Object`, to which is mapped on JVM).

Answer (score 3):

### Why there is the out variance annotation?

This is expected behavior of the [Bounded Class Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11) in kotlin 1.1.

We know an instance of subclass can be assign to a supperclass, for example:

```
val long:Number = 1L;
val int:Number = 1;
```

We also know generic inheritance is not like class inheritance, for example:

```
val long:KClass<Long> = Long::class;
val number:KClass<Number> = long;
//                           ^
// can't be compiled, required KClass<Number> but found KClass<Number>
```

So we makes the code to be compiled by using [Generic Type Projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) as below:

```
val number:KClass<out Number>  = long;
```

In Short, an variable of supperclass (`Number`) can be assign to an instances of any its subclasses (`Long`, `Int`, `Double` and .etc), but when get the `KClass` reference from the `Number` reference it should be return a `KClass<out Number>` rather than `KClass<Number>`, because `KClass<Int>` is not a subtype of the `KClass<Number>`.

The same rule applies in java, for example:

```
Number number = 1L;

Class<? extends Number> type = number.getClass();
```

### Why is it not KClass (because T's erasure is Any)?

Because your method uses generic parameter `T`, but `java.lang.Object#getClass` don't uses any generic parameter at all and its return type is `Class<? extends Object>`.

However, the [T#javaClass](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMapping.kt#L95-L97) property takes a generic parameter `T` and you can see the code below that kotin cast a `Class<?>` to a `Class<T>`. so the [Upper Bounded Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) of the `o::class` in the `foo` method is `KClass<? extends T>` rather than `KClass<? extends Object>` in java.

```
public inline val <T: Any> T.javaClass : Class<T>
   @Suppress("UsePropertyAccessSyntax")
   get() = (this as java.lang.Object).getClass()   as Class<T>
   // force to casting a Class<?> to a Class<T> ---^
```

A `KClass<? extends T>` is a subtype of `KClass<?>`, according to [LISP principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you can't assign a superclass instance to a subclass type.

```
fun <T : Any> foo(value: T) {
    val type: Class<out T> = (value as java.lang.Object).getClass();
    //   ^
    // Compilation Error:
    // you can't assign Class<? extends Object> to a Class<? extends T>
}
```

you can also see the method generic signature as below:

```
val noneGenericParametersMethod= Object::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getClass")!!
val genericParametersMethod by lazy {
    val it = object {
        fun <T : Any> foo(): Class<out T> = TODO();
    };
    return@lazy it.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("foo")!!;
}

println(genericParametersMethod.toGenericString())
//      ^--- its return type is java.lang.Class<? extends T>

println(noneGenericParametersMethod.toGenericString())
//      ^--- its return type is java.lang.Class<? extends Object>
```

Base on the above, the expression `o::class` actually returns a [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `KClass` rather than a parameterized type `KClass<out T>`, and a [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) can be assign to any [Parameterized Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html),  However, kotlin has no [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), so kotlin compiler narrow the raw type `KClass` into the parameterized type `KClass<out T>`, just like as narrow an `List<*>` to an `Iterable<*>`. an example of [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) in java:

```
Box rawBox = new Box();           // rawBox is a raw type of Box<T>
Box<Integer> intBox = rawBox;     // warning: unchecked conversion
```

### Why java can't assign T.getClass() into a Class<? extends T>?

If you get deep into the documentation of the [java.lang.Object#getClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) method, you will found the result as below:

> The actual result type is *Class<? extends **|X|**>* where **|X|** is the erasure of the **static type** of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

"**The erasure of the static type**": which means `|X|` is the bounded type rather than the actual generic argument type in runtime, for example:

```
// Object.getClass() using the bounded static type `Number`
//         v    
<T extends Number> Class<? extends Number> foo(T value){
    return value.getClass();
}
```

Comment: All right, I got your point. But here I got another question: shouldn't `o::class` in question body be of type `KClass<out Any>`? This is what Java does.

Comment: @glee8e why shouldn't?

Comment: But in my test `val kClass: KClass<out T> = o::class` compiles all fine, which indicate `o::class` isn't `KClass<out Any>`, but `KClass<out T>`.

Comment: @glee8e what are you meaning is you can't assign `o::class` to a `KClass<out Any>` variable? if it is don't, it is a kotlin bug. since the `KClass<out T>` is a subtype of the `KClass<out Any>`.

Comment: @glee8e hi, it works fine in my machine. `val type: KClass<out Any> = o::class`

Comment: You can't do `Class<? extends T> clazz=o.getClass();` in java, but you can do `val kClass: KClass<out T> = o::class`. This is what I'm interested in. Sorry for the late reply, as I'm about to go sleeping.

Comment: Shouldn't in the second snippet the comment rather be // can't be compiled, required KClass<Number> but found KClass<Long> instead of // can't be compiled, required KClass<Number> but found KClass<Number>?